# Can I transform data with prcomp or some other PCA function in R, without fitting to the data?

Tags: r, pca

I want to do something similar to [sklearn's PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) where I can .fit_transform() training data, and then use that to .transform() test data, but in R.  So far I've found `prcomp` and `princomp`, but I don't know how I can do this with those functions.

Comment: sweet, an anonymous downvote.  Is it that bad of a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this? (I'm using two subsets of the `iris` data for training and testing.)

```
pcs <- prcomp(iris[1:100, -5])
test_scores <- predict(pcs, newdata = iris[101:150, ])
```

Comment: I believe that is it.  I will have to compare with the sklearn function and make sure this comes to the same or similar result.